# Pandas: reorder column based on column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame that looks like this

[image]
[image]

Now the column name was converted from date format to `%b %Y` format and it is from Jan 2019 to Oct-2021. I want to reorder the column names based on the date and not alphabatically.

How do I do that?
I used the following line but it does not seem to work

```
table.sort_index(axis='columns', level='Date')
```

Edit: Here is the output from `print(table.head(10).to_dict(orient='list'))`

```
{('AADT', 'Apr 2019'): [4180.722222222223, 18075.733333333334, 1304536.8333333333, 62335.3, 1039.3333333333333, 9797.733333333334, 62949.36666666667, 527094.5333333333, 7893.0625, 10071.620689655172], ('AADT', 'Apr 2020'): [31081.166666666668, 17484.366666666665, 753747.0, 36726.03333333333, nan, 9451.0, 24169.966666666667, 292953.73333333334, 8537.1, 5484.466666666666], ('AADT', 'Apr 2021'): [2231.7272727272725, 21075.266666666666, 1109779.4666666666, 71246.8, nan, 10868.48275862069, 25227.2, 418751.43333333335, nan, 10701.863636363636], ('AADT', 'Aug 2019'): [2904.2903225806454, 20891.645161290322, 1466448.1935483871, 50817.6129032258, 1342.6666666666667, 8048.612903225807, 55199.54838709677, 609280.2903225806, 8958.258064516129, 10431.483870967742], ('AADT', 'Aug 2020'): [10822.379310344828, 12799.1, 679384.7741935484, 38622.54838709677, 1655.5, 5720.4838709677415, 12387.90322580645, 252135.5806451613, 9662.724137931034, 12194.724137931034], ('AADT', 'Aug 2021'): [3887.3225806451615, 12065.483870967742, 940915.0645161291, 59411.48387096774, 1863.5652173913043, 4154.129032258064, 23908.516129032258, 383140.6129032258, 17013.612903225807, 17311.483870967742], ('AADT', 'Dec 2019'): [nan, 29175.0, 1504749.322580645, 73835.83870967742, nan, 7232.142857142857, 61149.25, 584672.7096774194, nan, 8295.739130434782], ('AADT', 'Dec 2020'): [13414.380952380952, 13985.129032258064, 691473.6129032258, 33008.12903225807, nan, 10286.807692307691, 5184.032258064516, 256402.03225806452, 13108.444444444445, 9272.064516129032], ('AADT', 'Feb 2019'): [3646.4285714285716, 15604.5, 1044447.1428571428, 46783.96428571428, nan, 7491.285714285715, 19002.428571428572, 391334.5, 6558.107142857143, 6011.964285714285], ('AADT', 'Feb 2020'): [7531.482758620689, 18667.241379310344, 1107406.2068965517, 53251.24137931035, nan, 6785.379310344828, 20535.96551724138, 409618.5172413793, 8480.586206896553, 9712.620689655172], ('AADT', 'Feb 2021'): [2889.1428571428573, 13605.75, 1027667.6428571428, 66543.21428571429, nan, 11329.857142857143, 16417.25, 387610.75, 17206.2, 12769.392857142857], ('AADT', 'Jan 2019'): [3825.8709677419356, 16945.354838709678, 1043053.9677419355, 43416.3870967742, nan, 7369.064516129032, 17330.064516129034, 390853.5483870968, 9425.709677419354, 7200.580645161291], ('AADT', 'Jan 2020'): [2249.451612903226, 21037.225806451614, 1062939.0, 56543.54838709677, nan, 7452.225806451613, 21468.709677419356, 395211.0, 8022.967741935484, 8072.5161290322585], ('AADT', 'Jan 2021'): [2171.714285714286, 13143.032258064517, 872891.9354838709, 50554.645161290326, nan, 7621.740740740741, 8855.290322580646, 331211.67741935485, 10596.066666666668, 14136.161290322581], ('AADT', 'Jul 2019'): [2939.36, 18458.827586206895, 1490796.0, 64612.83870967742, 3319.1785714285716, 7838.290322580645, 64218.87096774193, 595895.3548387097, 11158.933333333332, 10345.967741935483], ('AADT', 'Jul 2020'): [8153.653846153846, 17704.423076923078, 696114.2903225806, 44171.967741935485, 1810.5172413793102, 5099.896551724138, 15129.129032258064, 258649.74193548388, 9227.23076923077, 10859.423076923076], ('AADT', 'Jul 2021'): [2941.3870967741937, 14229.064516129032, 1016602.3870967742, 55530.58064516129, 1884.4516129032259, 4855.870967741936, 31988.870967741936, 425938.12903225806, 16346.0, 18524.612903225807], ('AADT', 'Jun 2019'): [3332.0344827586205, 15839.033333333333, 1372660.5, 61044.5, 3884.7241379310344, 8082.433333333333, 60063.96666666667, 569774.2, 14599.333333333334, 12828.5], ('AADT', 'Jun 2020'): [6245.888888888889, 15431.518518518518, 825799.3, 43901.5, 1867.7333333333333, 8874.068965517241, 21052.633333333335, 302394.7, 10843.037037037036, 9797.111111111111], ('AADT', 'Jun 2021'): [3416.4615384615386, 58768.5, 907133.0, 50799.166666666664, 1987.8, 4894.8, 22486.766666666666, 393780.26666666666, nan, 17403.958333333332], ('AADT', 'Mar 2019'): [3190.3870967741937, 17057.709677419356, 1185417.2258064516, 54922.096774193546, nan, 9740.612903225807, 29554.74193548387, 456925.3870967742, 8201.37037037037, 9367.838709677419], ('AADT', 'Mar 2020'): [19192.516129032258, 17663.935483870966, 830373.1612903225, 55640.58064516129, nan, 9049.0, 21661.967741935485, 316354.29032258067, 8921.838709677419, 8638.612903225807], ('AADT', 'Mar 2021'): [1871.4347826086957, 17696.4, 1143384.5161290322, 75820.4, nan, 11566.3, 19212.833333333332, 430195.5806451613, nan, 14244.333333333334], ('AADT', 'May 2019'): [3238.0, 13838.032258064517, 1332669.935483871, 56042.77419354839, 2129.6875, 9247.548387096775, 56724.709677419356, 552480.3225806452, 11927.806451612903, 15388.41935483871], ('AADT', 'May 2020'): [15637.58064516129, 17504.322580645163, 855213.2903225806, 48857.903225806454, 1828.3636363636363, 10741.548387096775, 26456.83870967742, 319674.70967741933, 14051.032258064517, 10396.193548387097], ('AADT', 'May 2021'): [3893.6666666666665, 13900.129032258064, 903837.4193548387, 56877.16129032258, 1921.6, 6080.0, 29688.09677419355, 378961.32258064515, nan, 15112.0], ('AADT', 'Nov 2019'): [nan, 22217.85714285714, 1503773.3333333333, 66929.6, nan, 9282.6, 82848.0, 571871.2333333333, nan, 7841.555555555556], ('AADT', 'Nov 2020'): [24571.65, 20366.758620689656, 691888.9666666667, 33084.26666666667, nan, 14329.310344827587, 7821.266666666666, 264809.7, 15502.521739130434, 14558.172413793103], ('AADT', 'Oct 2019'): [1925.4444444444443, 22052.47619047619, 1498169.3870967743, 54511.93548387097, nan, 9876.9, 73759.85714285714, 587274.3548387097, 10594.777777777777, 9077.333333333334], ('AADT', 'Oct 2020'): [22728.129032258064, 22289.16129032258, 670292.2903225806, 32471.032258064515, nan, 9804.483870967742, 6325.580645161291, 250591.5806451613, 10681.37037037037, 10965.645161290322], ('AADT', 'Oct 2021'): [3264.7, 22671.533333333333, 1001493.1, 61869.86666666667, nan, 4570.413793103448, 28537.5, 374477.4, 12551.366666666667, 14900.2], ('AADT', 'Sep 2019'): [4031.9666666666667, 24609.266666666666, 1453336.2333333334, 54464.63333333333, nan, 9714.9, 57786.4, 631562.7, 11894.933333333332, 13868.266666666666], ('AADT', 'Sep 2020'): [30643.608695652172, 17740.076923076922, 709198.5333333333, 35773.6, nan, 7293.814814814815, 10384.933333333332, 256959.9, 9393.421052631578, 12787.739130434782], ('AADT', 'Sep 2021'): [2784.2, 14646.133333333333, 980093.1, 60560.36666666667, nan, 4127.1, 25578.133333333335, 366471.1, 14351.533333333333, 10283.966666666667]}
```

Here is the output from `print(table.head(5))`

```
                                                                             AADT  \
Date                                                                     Apr 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       4.180722e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       1.807573e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.304537e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       6.233530e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0       1.039333e+03   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Apr 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        31081.166667   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        17484.366667   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       753747.000000   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        36726.033333   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Apr 2021   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       2.231727e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.107527e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.109779e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       7.124680e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Aug 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       2.904290e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.089165e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.466448e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       5.081761e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0       1.342667e+03   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Aug 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        10822.379310   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        12799.100000   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       679384.774194   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        38622.548387   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0         1655.500000   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Aug 2021   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0         3887.322581   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        12065.483871   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       940915.064516   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        59411.483871   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0         1863.565217   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Dec 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0                NaN   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.917500e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.504749e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       7.383584e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Dec 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        13414.380952   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        13985.129032   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       691473.612903   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        33008.129032   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Feb 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       3.646429e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       1.560450e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.044447e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       4.678396e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Feb 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       7.531483e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       1.866724e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.107406e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       5.325124e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                     ...  \
Date                                                                 ...   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS  ...   
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       ...   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       ...   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       ...   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       ...   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0       ...   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      May 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        15637.580645   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        17504.322581   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       855213.290323   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        48857.903226   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0         1828.363636   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      May 2021   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0         3893.666667   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        13900.129032   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       903837.419355   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        56877.161290   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0         1921.600000   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Nov 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0                NaN   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.221786e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.503773e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       6.692960e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Nov 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        24571.650000   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        20366.758621   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       691888.966667   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        33084.266667   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Oct 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       1.925444e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.205248e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.498169e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       5.451194e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Oct 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        22728.129032   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        22289.161290   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       670292.290323   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        32471.032258   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Oct 2021   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       3.264700e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.267153e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.001493e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       6.186987e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                   \
Date                                                                     Sep 2019   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0       4.031967e+03   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0       2.460927e+04   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       1.453336e+06   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0       5.446463e+04   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                NaN   

                                                                                    \
Date                                                                      Sep 2020   
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                  
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0        30643.608696   
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        17740.076923   
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       709198.533333   
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        35773.600000   
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN   

                                                                                    
Date                                                                      Sep 2021  
State Postal Code State FIPS County Name                County FIPS                 
AK                2.0        Aleutians East Borough     2013.0         2784.200000  
                             Aleutians West Census Area 2016.0        14646.133333  
                             Anchorage Municipality     2020.0       980093.100000  
                             Bethel Census Area         2050.0        60560.366667  
                             Bristol Bay Borough        2060.0                 NaN  

[5 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: Don’t post images of the data as we can’t test them. Instead, post a sample of the DataFrames and the expected output directly inside a code block. A nice way is to share the outputs of `print(df.head(10).to_dict(orient=‘list’))` along with `print(df.head(10))`. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: @HarryPlotter I have updated my question with outputs as requested. I have to do a df.head(5) since I ran past the character limit with df.head(10).

Comment: Thanks, much better now! I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the column level 'Date' is datetime-like in the beginning, the trick is to sort the 'Date' level as you did (`table.sort_index(axis='columns', level='Date')`) and only then convert that level to string format `%b %Y`.

Another option, if the 'Date' level is in the string format `%b %Y` from the beginning, is to pass a sorting function to the `key` parameter.

```
table = table.sort_index(axis='columns', level='Date', 
                         key= lambda dates: pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%b %Y'))
```

From the [`DateFrame.sort_index` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

> **key : callable, optional**
>
> If not None, apply the key function to the index values before sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the builtin sorted() function, with the notable difference that this key function should be vectorized. It should expect an Index and return an Index of the same shape. For MultiIndex inputs, the key is applied per level.

Comment: Assuming I can't sort my data frame before converting it to `%b %Y` format, is there a way I can sort the columns when it is in the given format? I tried the code snippet you gave and it doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: @PrashantKumar could you be more specific? What didn't work? do you get an error? the output is not sorted? Did you reassign the output of `sort_index` to `table`? The sorting is not done in-place.

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. The snipped code worked. Thanks a lot @HarryPlotter

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help ;)